# Handle multiple request Alamofire while Search

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm having SearchContoller and whenever user starts searching I have to display the result. But continuous API calls over here sometimes old result remains even if there is no data received from API.
How to queue them so that there won't be any misplaced data viewed.

```
    fileprivate func getData(searchString: String){
        getFriendList = false
        guard let currentUser = AppController.shared.currentUser else { return }
//        self.friendsList.removeAll()
        APIHandler.shared.doAPIGetCallForUrl(Constants.kcFindFriends + "?UserId=" + String(currentUser.userId) + "&seachString=" + searchString + "&PageNumber=" + String(pageNumber) , callback: { [weak self](success, jsonData, error) in
            guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
            guard success == true else {
//                weakSelf.findFriendsTableView.reloadData()
                return
            }
            guard let json = jsonData else { return }
            guard let findFriendList: [FriendList] = json.value() else { return }
            weakSelf.friendsList.append(contentsOf: findFriendList)
            weakSelf.findFriendsTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchString = searchText
    pageNumber = 1
    getData(searchString: searchString)
}
```

Comment: Add `NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(YourView.getData(searchString:)), object: search_Bar)` in `textDidChange` .

Comment: @BhavinRamani Sorry didn't get you.

Comment: You should cancel your previous request before making new one

Comment: How to do that in Alamofire ?

Comment: In `textDidChange` method just add this line after page Number  `NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(YourView.getData(searchString:)), object: search_Bar) `

Comment: What is `object: search_Bar` and how to pass the Text ?

Comment: You don't need to pass anything there this is just for canceling the request.

Comment: Issue solved or not?

Comment: @BhavinRamani No still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Define a var for request in your viewController and in its setter cancel any old request

```
var searchRequest: Request?{
    didSet{
        oldValue?.cancel()
    }
}
```

> In your function pass the request to that var, So whenever you'll make a new search it'll cancel the old one.

```
searchRequest = Alamofire.request("URL", method: .post, parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            //Handle response
})
```

Comment: What is request over here ?

Comment: Alamofire.request returns Request class

Comment: Gives error at `searchRequest = Alamofire.request`  Generic parameter 'T' cannot be inferred.

Answer (score -1):

@BhavinRamani Reply

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar!, textDidChange searchText: String!) {
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(YourView.getData(searchString:)), object: searchBar)


     if !searchBar.text.isEmpty {
        dispatch_after_delay(0.25) {
           searchString = searchText
           pageNumber = 1
          getData(searchString: searchString)
        }
    } else {


         }

}
```